# Is there something similar like a JScrollPane where you click buttons to reach hidden components like in Microsoft Word toolbox?

Tags: java, swing, ms-word, components, jscrollpane

So in Word toolbox there is an component which is similar to a `JScrollPane` but it just has two buttons where you can click to reach components which are not shown. 
Are they build their self or is there something similar as Component?

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: I do not believe such an object exists by default, but you could probably build it by making a stack pane with some buttons on the side. When the button's are clicked, you can refer to the stack pane's xPosition to move it. There's certainly more to it than that, but it's possible. Would probably be a bit of work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @geekTechnique. Just wanted to know if there is one before I build it myself. My idea would have been to create a jscrollpane without scrollbars and make buttons which scrolls to a specific value. But I will haave a look at the stackpanes.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081038/jtoolbar-show-arrow-if-too-many-buttons-were-added/39081973#39081973 for one possible solution.

Comment: @camickr Thank your very much. That is exactly what I was looking for :D